# Randomize algorithm three times for modified values

Tags: probability, algorithms

Let $F:\{0,\ldots,n-1\}\rightarrow\{0,\ldots,m-1\}$ be a function such that $$F((x+y)\bmod n)=(F(x)+F(y))\bmod m$$ for $0\leq x,y\leq n-1$. Now, $1/5$ of the values of $F(x)$ that we store have been changed by an adversary. We would like an algorithm such that given $z$, the algorithm returns the (original) value of $F(z)$ with high probability. Such an algorithm is that we randomize $k\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$, and output $F(z+k)-F(k)$. The algorithm is correct with probability at least $1-1/5-1/5=3/5$.

Now suppose we can repeat the algorithm three times. What should we do, and what is the probability that the new algorithm is correct? I think we randomize three values $k$, and output the majority of the three answers that we get (if the majority exists). We are correct with probability $(3/5)^3+3\cdot(3/5)^2(2/5)=81/125$.

Can we do something better?

Comment: This is exercise 1.18 from "Probability and Computing".

Comment: @Irvan Yes, that's correct. And I'm just going through the book myself, not as part of some homework. (Just to clarify if anyone doubts.)